# Spring security + LocaleResolver

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, locale

i need to change locale settings after successful Authentication.

LocaleResolver:

```
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lng" />
    </bean>

   <bean id="localeResolver"
     class="web.MyLocaleResolver">
   </bean>
```

---

```
   public class MyLocaleResolver extends AbstractLocaleResolver {

   private Locale default = Locale.ENGLISH;

       @Override
       public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest hsr) {
           return this.default;
       }

       @Override
       public void setLocale(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1,         Locale default) {
           this.default = default;
       }

   }
```

Security:

```
     <form-login login-page="/login" 
          authentication-success-handler- ref="MySuccessAuthHandler"/>
     <beans:bean id="MySuccessAuthHandler" class="web.MySuccessfulAuthenticationHandler">
         <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.htm"></beans:property>
     </beans:bean>
```

---

```
public class MySuccessfulAuthenticationHandler extends  SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler  {
  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {

        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request).setLocale(request, response, Locale.ENGLISH);
   }

}
```

When i try to set locale by `RequestContextUtils` i get NullPointer Exception.

Comment: Then look at the first line of the stack trace: it will tell you exactly at which line of which file the exception occurs. Your code is pretty strange: you seem to care about i18n although you support a unique Locale for every user: English.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`LocaleResolver` is exposed in request context by `DispatcherServlet`, whereas `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` is fired before request enters `DispatcherServlet` (actually, request that fired `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` never enters `DispatcherServlet`, because this handler performs a redirect).

Thus, you cannot access `LocaleResolver` via `RequestContextUtils` in this case. You can try to inject `LocaleResolver` into your `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` explicitly, for example, with autowiring.

Comment: I've been trying exactly that (autowiring it in) but I keep getting a null any ideas why?

Comment: Is the same for me, is always null. I tried this: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/750158-getting-localeresolver-in-the-authentication-success-handler-ref and always is null. Can you give an example please?

Answer (score 3):

The solution from Kafkaesque is not complete.

But even spring security documentation is wrong:

> The LocaleContextHolder needs to be set up to contain the correct
>   Locale before the filters are called. You can either do this in a
>   filter yourself (which must come before the Spring Security filters in
>   web.xml) or you can use Spring's RequestContextFilter.

see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#localization

You can not use `RequestContextFilter` as this filter is not aware of any `LocaleResolver` inside your applicationContext. It just uses the Locale from `request.getLocale()` which is the `Accept-Language` Header.

If you want to use your own LocaleResolver in this filter you need to write your own:

```
@Component
public class LocaleRequestContextFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter
{
    // basiert auf RequestContextFilter
    @Inject
    private LocaleResolver      localeResolver;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal ( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain ) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        ServletRequestAttributes attributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(request, response);
        initContextHolders(request, attributes);
        try
        {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        finally
        {
            resetContextHolders();
            attributes.requestCompleted();
        }
    }

    private void initContextHolders ( HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes )
    {
        LocaleContextHolder.setLocaleContext(buildLocaleContext(request));
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(requestAttributes, false);
    }

    private LocaleContext buildLocaleContext ( final HttpServletRequest request )
    {
        request.setAttribute(DispatcherServlet.LOCALE_RESOLVER_ATTRIBUTE, localeResolver);
        if (this.localeResolver instanceof LocaleContextResolver)
        {
            return ( (LocaleContextResolver) this.localeResolver ).resolveLocaleContext(request);
        }
        else
        {
            return new LocaleContext()
            {
                @Override
                public Locale getLocale ( )
                {
                    return localeResolver.resolveLocale(request);
                }
            };
        }
    }

    private void resetContextHolders ( )
    {
        LocaleContextHolder.resetLocaleContext();
        RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
    }
}
```

and then configure your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>localeRequestContextFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>localeRequestContextFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: tried but RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request) continue to be null.

Comment: @Robert:You are calling the wrong method. Javadoc for RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request) says "Return the LocaleResolver that has been bound to the request by the DispatcherServlet.". Inside the filter the DispatcherServlet hasn't run yet. And you don't wnat a localeResolver, you want the locale or the LocaleContext. Maybe you should ask a new question for this referencing the solution presented here .

Answer (score 2):

Even though the DispatcherServlet isn't normally reached when using Spring Security, you can add the RequestContextFilter BEFORE your security filter chain which exposes all the request attributes like the localeResolver.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Even though this should make your example work. For other people: another option is to use `WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(ServletContext)` passing it the ServletContext that is available in the HttpServletRequest