# LocaleResolver in filter null yet shows it has been autowired! Spring MVC 3.1.1/Spring Security 3.1.0

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, localization, filter, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.1.0 and Spring MVC 3.1.1.
I would like to be able to change the locale based on URL i.e.:

```
http://localhost:8080/abc?lang=fr
```

Now, this works under "normal" circumstances, i.e. going from one page to another page HOWEVER, in my application, if I go from a non-secure page to a secure page, it first hit's my login page, courtesy of Spring Security BEFORE it hits the page I want.

This is normal Spring Security behaviour (to intercept a secure resource) so there are no problems with this behavuour.

The problem is rather that the locale does not change when I arrive at the secured page!  It stays as the default locale.  i..e lang=fr is not parsed out.

I have played with defining the locale related beans inside dispatcher-servlet.xml AND outside, in an app-context file to do the following:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" p:paramName="lang" />
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" p:defaultLocale="en" />
```

I have also tried to split up the above 2 beans, having just *localResolver* in the app-context config.

I have done TONS of research on this and basically, I understand I need to change the locale manually.

Even the Spring Docs for Spring Security 3.1.0 say that you need your own "filter" or you can use RequestContextFilter.  RequestContextFilter, however does not parse out the locale param in the query String.

```
Spring Security relies on Spring's localization support in order to actually lookup   
the appropriate message. In order for this to work, you have to make sure that the 
locale from the incoming request is stored in Spring's 
org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder. Spring MVC's DispatcherServlet 
does this for your application automatically, but since Spring Security's filters are 
invoked before this, the LocaleContextHolder needs to be set up to contain the correct 
Locale before the filters are called.  You can either do this in a filter yourself 
(which must come before the Spring Security filters in web.xml) or you can use 
Spring's RequestContextFilter.
```

I would like to intercept the request BEFORE it hits the Controller and so, I have written my own filter.

My solution, based on what others have done as well, is to autowire the LocaleResolver.  When tomcat fires up, it shows in my logs that "localeResolver" has been autowired (otherwise the app would fail right there) HOWEVER at run time, localeResolver is NULL.

Again, there have been posts that say to define LocaleResolver in the application-context...I have done so but I still end up getting a null LocaleResolver when a request happens.

Any ideas?? Much appreciated.

p.s. the filter I have defined comes before the Spring Security filters.  I can debug it, it hits it first but then it dies because of the NPE on LocaleResolver.

Appreciate this, thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026320/spring-security-localeresolver

Answer (score 4):

Did you define the filter in web.xml? If so, then the filter class is not instantiated by Spring, it is instantiated by the servlet container. Spring cannot autowire what it does not know about.

The general solution here is to declare the `<filter-class>` in web.xml as [`org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html) and point the `targetBeanName` at a bean in your context, such as:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>My Locale Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>myLocaleFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

And in your Spring context, `<bean id="myLocaleFilter">` should point at your Filter class.

You might also find it convenient for your custom Filter class to extend [`GenericFilterBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean.html) rather than implementing the `Filter` interface directly.

Comment: It worked!  I went back however, and called my bean directly again, and strangely this time it worked as well.  I think it had to do with the scanning.  I used:    <context:annotation-config/>   in the context where my filter is defined (I am using multiple contexts managed through maven).  I'm extending from GenericFilterBean.  Thanks.

Comment: Although I'm wondering about what you are saying: "Did you define the filter in web.xml? If so, then the filter class is not instantiated by Spring, it is instantiated by the servlet container. Spring cannot autowire what it does not know about."  I did define it with: DelegatingFilterProxy so I think this is the way Spring knows about it.  I can see that the rest of the wiring can be done in multiple ways.

Comment: Yes - if you are using DelegatingFilterProxy already than my solution doesn't apply. However if you didn't have annotation-config before, then I don't think it would autowire classes by default.